# get_sub_field on repeater returns empty keys/values

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

**EDIT: Updated with code which outputs the array**

Should be noted I have other fields which work correctly, the issue is only with the repeater sub_fields.

```
// Needs to be updated to be more dynamic i know
function get_flexible_content_sections($name, $option = "") {
    // check if the flexible content field has rows of data
    if ( have_rows( $name, $option ) ):

        // loop through the rows of data
        while ( have_rows( $name, $option ) ) : the_row(); ?>

            <section class="section <?= get_sub_field( "class" ) ?>">
                <div class="section-content clear">

                    <?php while ( have_rows( "section" ) ) : the_row();
                        if ( get_row_layout() == 'one_width_cols' ) : ?>

                            <div class="full-width-col cols-12">
                                <?php while ( have_rows( "module_1" ) ) : the_row();
                                    get_layout_modules( get_row_layout() );
                                endwhile; ?>
                            </div>

                        <?php elseif ( get_row_layout() == 'two_width_cols' ) : ?>

                            <div class="half-width-col col-1 cols-6">
                                <?php while ( have_rows( "module_1" ) ) : the_row();
                                    get_layout_modules( get_row_layout() );
                                endwhile; ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="half-width-col col-2 cols-6 last">
                                <?php while ( have_rows( "module_2" ) ) : the_row();
                                    get_layout_modules( get_row_layout() );
                                endwhile; ?>
                            </div>

                        <?php elseif ( get_row_layout() == 'three_width_cols' ) : ?>

                            <div class="three-width-col col-1 cols-4">
                                <?php while ( have_rows( "module_1" ) ) : the_row();
                                    get_layout_modules( get_row_layout() );
                                endwhile; ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="three-width-col col-2 cols-4">
                                <?php while ( have_rows( "module_2" ) ) : the_row();
                                    get_layout_modules( get_row_layout() );
                                endwhile; ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="three-width-col col-3 cols-4 last">
                                <?php while ( have_rows( "module_3" ) ) : the_row();
                                    get_layout_modules( get_row_layout() );
                                endwhile; ?>
                            </div>

                        <?php elseif ( get_row_layout() == 'four_width_cols' ) : ?>

                            <div class="four-width-col col-1 cols-3">
                                <?php while ( have_rows( "module_1" ) ) : the_row();
                                    get_layout_modules( get_row_layout() );
                                endwhile; ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="four-width-col col-2 cols-3">
                                <?php while ( have_rows( "module_2" ) ) : the_row();
                                    get_layout_modules( get_row_layout() );
                                endwhile; ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="four-width-col col-3 cols-3">
                                <?php while ( have_rows( "module_3" ) ) : the_row();
                                    get_layout_modules( get_row_layout() );
                                endwhile; ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="four-width-col col-4 cols-3 last">
                                <?php while ( have_rows( "module_4" ) ) : the_row();
                                    get_layout_modules( get_row_layout() );
                                endwhile; ?>
                            </div>

                        <?php elseif ( get_row_layout() == 'five_width_cols' ) : ?>

                            <div class="five-width-col col-1 cols-2">
                                <?php while ( have_rows( "module_1" ) ) : the_row();
                                    get_layout_modules( get_row_layout() );
                                endwhile; ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="five-width-col  col-2 cols-2">
                                <?php while ( have_rows( "module_2" ) ) : the_row();
                                    get_layout_modules( get_row_layout() );
                                endwhile; ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="five-width-col col-3 cols-2">
                                <?php while ( have_rows( "module_3" ) ) : the_row();
                                    get_layout_modules( get_row_layout() );
                                endwhile; ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="five-width-col col-4 cols-2">
                                <?php while ( have_rows( "module_4" ) ) : the_row();
                                    get_layout_modules( get_row_layout() );
                                endwhile; ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="five-width-col col-5 cols-2 last">
                                <?php while ( have_rows( "module_5" ) ) : the_row();
                                    get_layout_modules( get_row_layout() );
                                endwhile; ?>
                            </div>

                        <?php endif;
                    endwhile; ?>

                </div> <!--end section-content-->
            </section>
        <?php endwhile;
    else :
        // no layouts found
    endif;
}

function layout_module_slider() {
    ob_start();

    ?><div class="layout-module-slider <?= get_sub_field('class'); ?>">
        <?php
        $files = get_sub_field('img_slider');
        // pre is a function which wraps a value with print_r
        pre($files); // <-- prints the "empty" array
        if(count($files) > 0 ) {
            echo slick_slider_func($files);
        } else {
            echo "No images available";
        }
        ?>
    </div><?php

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

---

**ORIGINAL:**

I have a nested repeater field inside layers of flexible contents. The purpose of which is to add images which are outputted to a slider.

The image ID's are stored in the database, but when I try to output them using get_sub_field, this is what i get:

[image: get_sub_field output]

I have build the field group programatically, which works in the backend as seen below. The backend equivalent for the above output:

[image: Backend slider image with text]

The entire ACF settings/program:

```
if ( function_exists( 'acf_add_local_field_group' ) ):

    add_action("init", "tryangle_generate_sections_fields");
    function tryangle_generate_sections_fields() {
        $indhold_gd = array(
            'key' => 'group_indhold',
            'title' => 'Indhold',
            'fields' => array (),
            'location' => array (
                array (
                    array (
                        'param' => 'post_type',
                        'operator' => '==',
                        'value' => 'page',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'position' => 'acf_after_title',
            'menu_order' => 0,
        );
        generate_fields( "indhold224466", $indhold_gd );
    }

endif;

function generate_fields($uniqid, $group_data)
{
    if(empty($uniqid) || empty($group_data)) return;

    // Sets a unique affix on all keys
    $uiq = $uniqid;
    // Sets the group_data with locations etc.
    $group_data['key'] = $group_data['key'] . '_' . $uiq;

    // Available modules
    $modules = array(
        array(
            'key'        => '5b2cefcfdea9da_'.$uiq,
            'name'       => 'text',
            'label'      => 'Text',
            'display'    => 'block',
            'sub_fields' => array(
                array(
                    'key'               => 'field_5b2d13ddfb10ba_'.$uiq,
                    'label'             => 'Text',
                    'name'              => 'text',
                    'type'              => 'wysiwyg',
                    'instructions'      => '',
                    'required'          => 0,
                    'conditional_logic' => 0,
                    'wrapper'           => array(
                        'width' => '',
                        'class' => '',
                        'id'    => '',
                    ),
                    'default_value'     => '',
                    'tabs'              => 'all',
                    'toolbar'           => 'full',
                    'media_upload'      => 1,
                    'delay'             => 0,
                ),
            ),
            'min'        => '',
            'max'        => '',
        ),
        array (
            'key' => '5b3e2a167d2ee_'.$uiq,
            'name' => 'image_slider',
            'label' => 'Slider',
            'display' => 'block',
            'sub_fields' => array (
                array (
                    'key' => 'field_5b3e2a3047a45_'.$uiq,
                    'label' => 'Slider',
                    'name' => 'img_slider',
                    'type' => 'repeater',
                    'instructions' => '',
                    'required' => 0,
                    'conditional_logic' => 0,
                    'wrapper' => array (
                        'width' => '',
                        'class' => '',
                        'id' => '',
                    ),
                    'collapsed' => '',
                    'min' => 0,
                    'max' => 0,
                    'layout' => 'table',
                    'button_label' => 'Tilføj billede',
                    'sub_fields' => array (
                        array (
                            'key' => 'field_5b3e2a3b47a46_'.$uiq,
                            'label' => 'Billede',
                            'name' => 'img',
                            'type' => 'image',
                            'instructions' => '',
                            'required' => 0,
                            'conditional_logic' => 0,
                            'wrapper' => array (
                                'width' => '20',
                                'class' => '',
                                'id' => '',
                            ),
                            'return_format' => 'array',
                            'preview_size' => 'thumbnail',
                            'library' => 'all',
                            'min_width' => '',
                            'min_height' => '',
                            'min_size' => '',
                            'max_width' => '',
                            'max_height' => '',
                            'max_size' => '',
                            'mime_types' => '',
                        ),
                        array (
                            'key' => 'field_5b3e2a5647a47_'.$uiq,
                            'label' => 'Billedetekst',
                            'name' => 'img_text',
                            'type' => 'wysiwyg',
                            'instructions' => '',
                            'required' => 0,
                            'conditional_logic' => 0,
                            'wrapper' => array (
                                'width' => '',
                                'class' => '',
                                'id' => '',
                            ),
                            'default_value' => '',
                            'tabs' => 'all',
                            'toolbar' => 'full',
                            'media_upload' => 1,
                            'delay' => 0,
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'min' => '',
            'max' => '',
        ),
        array(
            'key'        => '5b2cf0bbbf1c9a_'.$uiq,
            'name'       => 'posts_slider',
            'label'      => 'Indlægsslider',
            'display'    => 'block',
            'sub_fields' => array(
                array(
                    'key'               => 'field_5b2d13ddfb110a_'.$uiq,
                    'label'             => 'Indlægskategori',
                    'name'              => 'post_category',
                    'type'              => 'taxonomy',
                    'instructions'      => '',
                    'required'          => 0,
                    'conditional_logic' => 0,
                    'wrapper'           => array(
                        'width' => '',
                        'class' => '',
                        'id'    => '',
                    ),
                    'taxonomy'          => 'category',
                    'field_type'        => 'select',
                    'allow_null'        => 0,
                    'add_term'          => 0,
                    'save_terms'        => 0,
                    'load_terms'        => 0,
                    'return_format'     => 'object',
                    'multiple'          => 0,
                ),
                array(
                    'key'               => 'field_5b2d13ddfb111a_'.$uiq,
                    'label'             => 'Udseende',
                    'name'              => 'style',
                    'type'              => 'select',
                    'instructions'      => '',
                    'required'          => 0,
                    'conditional_logic' => 0,
                    'wrapper'           => array(
                        'width' => '',
                        'class' => '',
                        'id'    => '',
                    ),
                    'choices'           => array(
                        'Slider' => 'Slider',
                        'Grid'   => 'Grid',
                    ),
                    'default_value'     => array(),
                    'allow_null'        => 0,
                    'multiple'          => 0,
                    'ui'                => 0,
                    'ajax'              => 0,
                    'return_format'     => 'value',
                    'placeholder'       => '',
                ),
            ),
            'min'        => '',
            'max'        => '',
        ),
    );
    // Section columns
    $columns = array(
        array(
            'key'        => 'field_one_width_cols_'.$uiq,
            'name'       => 'one_width_cols',
            'label'      => 'En kolonne',
            'display'    => 'block',
            'sub_fields' => array(
            ),
            'min'        => '',
            'max'        => '',
            'cols'       => 1,
        ),
        array(
            'key'        => 'field_two_width_cols_'.$uiq,
            'name'       => 'two_width_cols',
            'label'      => 'To kolonner',
            'display'    => 'block',
            'sub_fields' => array(),
            'min'        => '',
            'max'        => '',
            'cols'       => 2,
        ),
        array(
            'key'        => 'field_three_width_cols_'.$uiq,
            'name'       => 'three_width_cols',
            'label'      => 'Tre kolonner',
            'display'    => 'block',
            'sub_fields' => array(),
            'min'        => '',
            'max'        => '',
            'cols'       => 3,
        ),
        array(
            'key'        => 'field_four_width_cols_'.$uiq,
            'name'       => 'four_width_cols',
            'label'      => 'Fire kolonner',
            'display'    => 'block',
            'sub_fields' => array(),
            'min'        => '',
            'max'        => '',
            'cols'       => 4,
        ),
        array(
            'key'        => 'field_five_width_cols_'.$uiq,
            'name'       => 'five_width_cols',
            'label'      => 'Fem kolonner',
            'display'    => 'block',
            'sub_fields' => array(),
            'min'        => '',
            'max'        => '',
            'cols'       => 5,
        )
    );

    /**
     * Add columns to sections
     */
    $loops = 1;
    foreach ($columns as $key => $col)
    {
        // loop for the amount of columns available (5 columns)
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $col['cols']; $i++) {
            $width = 100 / $loops;
            $columns[$key]['sub_fields'][] = array(
                'key'               => 'field_module_'.$i.'_'.$uiq,
                'label'             => 'Modul',
                'name'              => 'module_'.$i,
                'type'              => 'flexible_content',
                'instructions'      => '',
                'required'          => 0,
                'conditional_logic' => 0,
                'wrapper'           => array(
                    'width' => $width,
                    'class' => '',
                    'id'    => '',
                ),
                'min'               => '',
                'max'               => '',
                'button_label'      => 'Tilføj modul',
                'layouts'           => $modules,
            );
        }

        $loops++;
    }

    // Add field group "Indhold"
    acf_add_local_field_group($group_data);

    // Add sections to the "Indhold" field group
    acf_add_local_field(array(
        'parent'        => 'group_indhold_'.$uiq,
        'key'           => 'field_sections_'.$uiq,
        'label'         => 'Sektioner',
        'name'          => 'sections',
        'type'          => 'flexible_content',
        'button_label'  => 'Tilføj sektion',
        'layouts' => array(
            array(
                'key'        => 'layout_section_'.$uiq,
                'name'       => 'section',
                'label'      => 'Sektion',
                'display'    => 'block',
                'sub_fields' => array(
                    array(
                        'key'               => 'field_section_'.$uiq,
                        'label'             => 'Sektion',
                        'name'              => 'section',
                        'type'              => 'flexible_content',
                        'instructions'      => '',
                        'required'          => 0,
                        'conditional_logic' => 0,
                        'wrapper'           => array(
                            'width' => '',
                            'class' => '',
                            'id'    => '',
                        ),
                        'min'               => '',
                        'max'               => '',
                        'button_label'      => 'Tilføj kolonner',
                        'layouts'           => $columns,
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key'               => 'field_section_class_'.$uiq,
                        'label'             => 'Sektion class',
                        'name'              => 'class',
                        'type'              => 'text',
                        'instructions'      => '',
                        'required'          => 0,
                        'conditional_logic' => 0,
                        'wrapper'           => array(
                            'width' => '',
                            'class' => '',
                            'id'    => '',
                        ),
                        'default_value'     => '',
                        'placeholder'       => '',
                        'prepend'           => '',
                        'append'            => '',
                        'maxlength'         => '',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ));
}
```

Help is very much appreciated! I've been stuck with this the entire day now.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started over from scratch and redid all the fields in ACF, and added those programmatically carefully with uniquely generated keys (some of the keys were duplicates might have been the issue). The updated code now works thankfully.

Full code posted below (without output, should work with standard ACF docs).
I also added the crawler that replaces the field keys with unique keys.

Not sure where the fault lies in the original post, though this new code works and does entirely the same.

```
<?php

if ( function_exists( 'acf_add_local_field_group' ) ):

    add_action("init", "tryangle_generate_sections_fields");
    function tryangle_generate_sections_fields() {
        $indhold_gd = array(
            'key' => 'group_5b3f61bd82eba',
            'title' => 'Indhold',
            'location' => array (
                array (
                    array (
                        'param' => 'post_type',
                        'operator' => '==',
                        'value' => 'page',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'position' => 'acf_after_title',
            'menu_order' => 0,
            'style' => 'default',
            'label_placement' => 'top',
            'instruction_placement' => 'label',
            'hide_on_screen' => '',
            'active' => 1,
            'description' => '',
        );
        generate_fields( "allpages", $indhold_gd );
    }


endif;

/**
 * Alters the ACF keys of the passed array, with the pass key affix
 * @param $fields array Take ACF fields array as input.
 * @param $randkey string String which is appended on the key
 *
 * @return array Returns passed array with altered keys
 */
function crawl_generate_keys($fields, $randkey) {
    if(is_array($fields))
    {
        foreach ( $fields as $fk => $f )
        {
            if(!empty(is_array($fields[$fk]['sub_fields'])))
            {
                $fields[$fk]['sub_fields'] = crawl_generate_keys($fields[$fk]['sub_fields'], $randkey);
            }
            else if(!empty(is_array($fields[$fk]['layouts'])))
            {
                $fields[$fk]['layouts'] = crawl_generate_keys($fields[$fk]['layouts'], $randkey);
            }

            $fields[$fk]['key'] = $fields[$fk]['key'] . '_' . $randkey;
        }
    } else {
        $fields['key'] = $fields['key'] . '_' . $randkey;
    }

    return $fields;
}

function generate_fields($uniqid, $gd)
{
    // Declare the available layout modules
    // The different layouts, such as slider, text field, statement slider
    $layouts = array(
        array (
            'key' => '5b3f63d3bc38c_' . $uniqid,
            'name' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Text',
            'display' => 'block',
            'sub_fields' => array (
                array (
                    'key' => 'field_5b3f641bb0588_' . $uniqid,
                    'label' => 'Text',
                    'name' => 'text',
                    'type' => 'wysiwyg',
                    'instructions' => '',
                    'required' => 0,
                    'conditional_logic' => 0,
                    'wrapper' => array (
                        'width' => '',
                        'class' => '',
                        'id' => '',
                    ),
                    'default_value' => '',
                    'tabs' => 'all',
                    'toolbar' => 'full',
                    'media_upload' => 1,
                    'delay' => 0,
                ),
            ),
            'min' => '',
            'max' => '',
        ),
        array (
            'key' => '5b3f6425b0589_' . $uniqid,
            'name' => 'slider',
            'label' => 'Slider',
            'display' => 'block',
            'sub_fields' => array (
                array (
                    'key' => 'field_5b3f6428b058a_' . $uniqid,
                    'label' => 'Slider',
                    'name' => 'slider',
                    'type' => 'repeater',
                    'instructions' => '',
                    'required' => 0,
                    'conditional_logic' => 0,
                    'wrapper' => array (
                        'width' => '',
                        'class' => '',
                        'id' => '',
                    ),
                    'collapsed' => '',
                    'min' => 0,
                    'max' => 0,
                    'layout' => 'table',
                    'button_label' => 'Tilføj billede',
                    'sub_fields' => array (
                        array (
                            'key' => 'field_5b3f642fb058b_' . $uniqid,
                            'label' => 'Billede',
                            'name' => 'image',
                            'type' => 'image',
                            'instructions' => '',
                            'required' => 0,
                            'conditional_logic' => 0,
                            'wrapper' => array (
                                'width' => '20',
                                'class' => '',
                                'id' => '',
                            ),
                            'return_format' => 'array',
                            'preview_size' => 'thumbnail',
                            'library' => 'all',
                            'min_width' => '',
                            'min_height' => '',
                            'min_size' => '',
                            'max_width' => '',
                            'max_height' => '',
                            'max_size' => '',
                            'mime_types' => '',
                        ),
                        array (
                            'key' => 'field_5b3f6453b058c_' . $uniqid,
                            'label' => 'Billede tekst',
                            'name' => 'image_text',
                            'type' => 'wysiwyg',
                            'instructions' => '',
                            'required' => 0,
                            'conditional_logic' => 0,
                            'wrapper' => array (
                                'width' => '',
                                'class' => '',
                                'id' => '',
                            ),
                            'default_value' => '',
                            'tabs' => 'all',
                            'toolbar' => 'full',
                            'media_upload' => 1,
                            'delay' => 0,
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                array (
                    'key' => 'field_5b40ec12be700_' . $uniqid,
                    'label' => 'Slider class',
                    'name' => 'slider_class',
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'instructions' => '',
                    'required' => 0,
                    'conditional_logic' => 0,
                    'wrapper' => array (
                        'width' => '',
                        'class' => '',
                        'id' => '',
                    ),
                    'default_value' => '',
                    'placeholder' => '',
                    'prepend' => '',
                    'append' => '',
                    'maxlength' => '',
                ),

            ),
            'min' => '',
            'max' => '',
        ),
        array (
            'key' => '5b3f64a5b058d_' . $uniqid,
            'name' => 'statements',
            'label' => 'Udtalelser',
            'display' => 'block',
            'sub_fields' => array (
                array (
                    'key' => 'field_5b3f64b4b058e_' . $uniqid,
                    'label' => 'Udtalelser',
                    'name' => 'statements',
                    'type' => 'post_object',
                    'instructions' => '',
                    'required' => 0,
                    'conditional_logic' => 0,
                    'wrapper' => array (
                        'width' => '',
                        'class' => '',
                        'id' => '',
                    ),
                    'post_type' => array (
                        0 => 'udtalelser',
                    ),
                    'taxonomy' => array (
                    ),
                    'allow_null' => 0,
                    'multiple' => 1,
                    'return_format' => 'object',
                    'ui' => 1,
                ),
            ),
            'min' => '',
            'max' => '',
        ),
    );

    // Declare the avaialable columns
    // The key indicates amount columns for that column
    $columns = array (
        1 => array (
            'key' => '5b3f636009d7e1_' . $uniqid,
            'name' => 'one_width_cols',
            'label' => 'En kolonne',
            'display' => 'block',
            'sub_fields' => array(),
            'min' => '',
            'max' => '',
        ),
        2 => array (
            'key' => '5b3f636009d7e2_' . $uniqid,
            'name' => 'two_width_cols',
            'label' => 'To kolonner',
            'display' => 'block',
            'sub_fields' => array(),
            'min' => '',
            'max' => '',
        ),
        3 => array (
            'key' => '5b3f636009d7e3_' . $uniqid,
            'name' => 'three_width_cols',
            'label' => 'Tre kolonner',
            'display' => 'block',
            'sub_fields' => array(),
            'min' => '',
            'max' => '',
        ),
        4 => array (
            'key' => '5b3f636009d7e4_' . $uniqid,
            'name' => 'four_width_cols',
            'label' => 'Fire kolonner',
            'display' => 'block',
            'sub_fields' => array(),
            'min' => '',
            'max' => '',
        ),
        5 => array (
            'key' => '5b3f636009d7e5_' . $uniqid,
            'name' => 'five_width_cols',
            'label' => 'Fem kolonner',
            'display' => 'block',
            'sub_fields' => array(),
            'min' => '',
            'max' => '',
        ),
    );

    // Add layout modules to modules, add modules to columns
    foreach ($columns as $k => $c)
    {
        // Loop for every module to be added to the column
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $k; $i++)
        {
            $keyaffix = 'c' . $k . '_m' . $i;
            $wrapperWidth = 100 / $k;

            $insLayouts = crawl_generate_keys($layouts, $keyaffix);

            $columns[$k]['sub_fields'][] = array(
                'key' => 'field_5b3f63c1b0586_' . $keyaffix . '_' . $uniqid,
                'label' => 'Modul',
                'name' => 'module_' . $i,
                'type' => 'flexible_content',
                'instructions' => '',
                'required' => 0,
                'conditional_logic' => 0,
                'wrapper' => array (
                    'width' => $wrapperWidth,
                    'class' => '',
                    'id' => '',
                ),
                'button_label' => 'Tilføj modul',
                'min' => '',
                'max' => '',
                'layouts' => $insLayouts,
            );
        }
    }

    acf_add_local_field_group(array (
        'key' => $gd['key'] . '_'. $uniqid,
        'title' => $gd['title'],
        'fields' => array (
            array (
                'key' => 'field_5b3f61c74f5b2_' . $uniqid,
                'label' => 'Sektioner',
                'name' => 'sections',
                'type' => 'flexible_content',
                'instructions' => '',
                'required' => 0,
                'conditional_logic' => 0,
                'wrapper' => array (
                    'width' => '',
                    'class' => '',
                    'id' => '',
                ),
                'button_label' => 'Tilføj sektion',
                'min' => '',
                'max' => '',
                'layouts' => array (
                    array (
                        'key' => '5b3f61ce24ec5_' . $uniqid,
                        'name' => 'section',
                        'label' => 'Sektion',
                        'display' => 'block',
                        'sub_fields' => array (
                            array (
                                'key' => 'field_5b3f6359b0585_' . $uniqid,
                                'label' => 'Sektion',
                                'name' => 'section',
                                'type' => 'flexible_content',
                                'instructions' => '',
                                'required' => 0,
                                'conditional_logic' => 0,
                                'wrapper' => array (
                                    'width' => '',
                                    'class' => '',
                                    'id' => '',
                                ),
                                'button_label' => 'Tilføj kolonner',
                                'min' => '',
                                'max' => '',
                                'layouts' => $columns,
                            ),
                        ),
                        'min' => '',
                        'max' => '',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'location' => $gd['location'],
        'menu_order' => $gd['menu_order'],
        'position' => $gd['position'],
        'style' => $gd['style'],
        'label_placement' => $gd['label_placement'],
        'instruction_placement' => $gd['instruction_placement'],
        'hide_on_screen' => $gd['hide_on_screen'],
        'active' => $gd['active'],
        'description' => $gd['description'],
    ));
}
```

Comment: I voted-up because this answer and the question were both helpful (to me). Thanks and I'm glad you found a solution! =)

Comment: Hi Sally thank you kindly, and thank you for helping and trying, very much appreciated. Glad I could help you! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm not sure why it's empty:

```
pre($files); // <-- prints the "empty" array
```

However, you can replace this:

```
$files = get_sub_field('img_slider');
```

..with this: (manually build the data for `$files`)

```
$files = array();
if ( have_rows( 'img_slider' ) ) {
    // Loop through the repeater's fields and manually fill in the `$files` array.
    while ( have_rows( 'img_slider' ) ) : the_row();
        if ( $image = get_sub_field( 'img' ) ) {
            // These are just examples; just rename the keys, add more items, etc.
            // it's all up to you.
            $files[] = array(
                'url'  => $image['url'],
                'text' => get_sub_field( 'img_text' ),
                // ...
            );
        }
    endwhile;
}
//var_dump( $files );
```

### Additional Code

This loop may also help you, which I used to get to the slider items (i.e. image and its caption/text), starting from the `sections` field, which is the topmost-level field:

```
$post_id = false; // `false` defaults to the global `$post`
if ( have_rows( 'sections', $post_id ) ) :
    while ( have_rows( 'sections', $post_id ) ) : the_row(); // loop #1
        // With the current fields defined in `generate_fields()`, the 'class'
        // is only available in loop #1.
        $section_class = get_sub_field( 'class' );

        echo '<div class="' . esc_attr( $section_class ) . '">'; // start the section

        if ( have_rows( 'section' ) ) {
            while ( have_rows( 'section' ) ) : the_row(); // loop #2
                if ( have_rows( 'module_1' ) ) {
                    while ( have_rows( 'module_1' ) ) : the_row(); // loop #3
                        // In section #2 only.
                        the_sub_field( 'text' );

                        // In section #1 only.
                        if ( have_rows( 'img_slider' ) ) {
                            echo '<ul class="slider">';

                            while ( have_rows( 'img_slider' ) ) : the_row(); // loop #4
                                echo '<li class="slide-item">';

                                $image = get_sub_field( 'img' );
                                echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image['id'] );

                                the_sub_field( 'img_text' );

                                echo '</li>';
                            endwhile; // end loop #4

                            echo '</ul>';
                        }
                    endwhile; // end loop #3
                }
            endwhile; // end loop #2
        }

        echo '</div>'; // end section
    endwhile; // end loop #1
endif;
```

**Section #1 (`image-slider`)**

[image]

**Section #2 (`lorem-ipsum`)**

[image]

Comment: Hi Sally, thanks for you answer once more. I'm not sure if this would though.
I have since started over from scratch on this program, and redid all the fields in ACF while carefully generating unique keys for all the fields, in the new program (the keys might have something to do with it). The updated code thankfully works now.

Comment: Not a problem. I actually did see the duplicates, but I didn't know why did I not mention about them or even try to make them unique! I guess I thought you already tried that too. xD Btw, I deleted my previous answer.. but thanks for the vote-ups!